# Why do Fullerenes have even number of carbon atoms?

Tags: organic-chemistry

My teacher started a chapter called "Carbon and its compounds", Which is just an intro to organic chemistry . In which she taught about fullerenes structure and examples and also told that fullerenes have even number of carbon atoms. I got curious and asked why but she didn't answer me. So I went and googled it but still did not get any answer. Is there any exception or any reason behind it?

Comment: I think you should think merely on geometry. Rather than why is how they can form. It will be the same for some "regular" polyhedron of that type.

Comment: A guess, fullerenes structures are ascribed to have symmetry. To be symmetric around an axis of symmetry implies a factor of 2 in structural units. I was also contemplating as to whether it was related to a charge balance, but it said that fullerenes apparently possess a charge imbalance!

Comment: And how many carbons are in double bond? 2! If number wasn't even, then it would be a radical and two of them would bind to each other.

Comment: If some people in the room shake hands with each other, then the total number of shaked hands is even. It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of (closed) fullerenes is governed by Euler’s polyhedron formula: vertices (carbon atoms) + edges (bonds) - faces = 2. Geometric constraints determine that at least some of the faces must be pentagons or heptagons, and that the number of atoms must be even.